# What's the most elegant way to get the language codes from an MKV file with multiple audio tracks?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, mkv

I need a way to get the language codes from MKV files which have multiple audio tracks.

`ffmpeg` produces output which I could then filter using regular expressions but it doesn't seem very elegant:

```
$ ffmpeg -i file.mkv 2>&1 | grep Audio
Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: mp2, 48000 Hz, stereo, s16, 192 kb/s (default)
Stream #0:2(nar): Audio: mp2, 48000 Hz, mono, s16, 64 kb/s (default)
```

`mediainfo` has the ability to extract language information but in files with multiple tracks, it concatenates the codes into a single string:

```
$ mediainfo file.mkv --inform="Audio;%Language%"  
ennar
```

Is there a tool or command which will return language codes for multiple tracks in a nicer way, or a tool which would let me specify a track number and return the language code for that track only?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running this ffprobe command

```
ffprobe in.mp4 -show_entries stream=index:stream_tags=language -select_streams a -v 0 -of compact=p=0:nk=1
```

will produce this output

```
1|eng
2|deu
3|eng
4|eng
5|fre
```

Where the first field is the absolute stream index i.e. counting all types V/A/S and is 0-based.

```
ffprobe in.mp4 -show_entries stream=index:stream_tags=language -select_streams a:2 -v 0 -of compact=p=0:nk=1
```

will show only the third audio stream.

```
ffprobe in.mp4 -show_entries stream=index:stream_tags=language -select_streams 2 -v 0 -of compact=p=0:nk=1
```

will show only the third stream, whichever type it is.

Comment: Thank you! Is there a way to specify the track number and receive the language code for just that track?

Comment: Just saw comment above. Yes, `-select_streams a:2` for 3rd audio stream, or `-select_streams 5` for 6th stream (whatever type)